# What does the colon (:) in JavaScript represent?

Tags: javascript

This is probably a stupid noob question but what does the : represent in the following context:

```
var stuffToDo = {
    'bar' : function() {
        alert('the value was bar -- yay!');
    },

    'baz' : function() {
        alert('boo baz :(');
    },

    'default' : function() {
        alert('everything else is just ok');
    }
};

if (stuffToDo[foo]) {
    stuffToDo[foo]();
} else {
    stuffToDo['default']();
}
```

Is it storing the function to each of those variables?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is an [*object literal*  *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_Object_Initializers):

```
var obj = {
    key: value
};

// obj.key === value; // true
```

It assigns `value` to a property `key` of `obj`. While there are no restriction for what `value` can be (well, it must be something assignable), there are limitations for `key`: It must be either an [*identifier name*](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_7.6), a string literal or a numeric literal.

More details can be found in [section 11.1.5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5) of the ECMAScript specification.

The literal notation is similar to:

```
var stuffToDo = {}; // <-- empty object literal

stuffToDo.bar = function() {...};
// or stuffToDo['bar'] = ...

stuffToDo.baz = function() {...};
// or stuffToDo['baz'] = ...
```

The biggest difference is that when using an object literal, you cannot access other properties of the object *during the declaration*.

This will not work:

```
var obj = {
    foo: value,
    bar: obj.foo
};
```

whereas this does:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = value;
obj.bar = obj.foo;
```

---

For completeness, there are two other uses of colons in JavaScript:

- [Conditional (ternary) operator *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator):

  ```
  var val = condition ? true-value : false-value;
  ```
- [Labels *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

  ```
  someLabel: var x = 5;
  ```

Comment: That ECMAscript link has dated badly :\

Answer (score 4):

It is the **object literal notation** http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php

Comment: the link is broken :)