# What is the use of the following colon in javascript

Tags: javascript

Following code block executed successfully. I was wondering what would be the use of this labeling other than using for loops?

```
<script>

js:
{
   alert("x");  
}

</script>
```

Comment: That's a colon :P

Comment: Is this the actual and full code?

Comment: hth http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/labelled-blocks-useful/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you mark labels, a very bad practice which give the ability to implement the old 'goto', which is simple jump to code in sequential executing

Comment: There is no `goto` in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy They didn't say there's a `goto` operator or something, just used to implement "goto". In your answer, `break` is as good as `goto`

Comment: Breaking out of a nested loop using a label is, IMO, a pretty valid case for `goto`-like behaviour.

Comment: Well `goto` involves the unrestricted ability to jump *anywhere*.  There are implicit constraints on what can be done with `break` and `continue`.

Comment: Any working example using goto to jump to a label? i know they are used within loops. But I'm wondering if it is possible without.

Comment: @AliKemal If you're **needing** to jump to a specific line, it usually means you're doing something wrong. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Not trying anything special. Just came across to this creating labels and I was wondering how do we jump to these labels then if we are able create them. I understand the use in loops though.

Comment: As Pointy mentioned before it does have huge limitations in javascript, but I think you would have more luck using functions.

Answer (score 6):

The `:` has a few uses in javascript, that I know of anyway.

1. `ternary operator` - used to evaluate an `if` statement in a single line:

   ```
   var x = "yes" == "yes" ? true : false;
   ```

   The above line of code is functionally equivalent to:

   ```
   if("yes" == "yes"){
       var x = true;
   }
   else{
       var x = false;
   }
   ```
2. Mark the beginning of a code block - Move to a block of code

   ```
   begin:
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       break begin;
   }
   ```
3. Object Literals - Thanks @Ian for the reminder

   ```
   var someObject= {
       item: 'some value',
       anotherItem: 2 // Can put any type of variable here
   };
   ```

   This type of notation is commonly seen when using [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: What about in object literals? :)

Comment: @Ian How could I forget, updating now.

Answer (score 3):

It's a labeled statement. You can use labeled statements with a form of the `break` and `continue` statements:

```
outer: for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    if (somethingBad())
      break outer;
  }
}
```

It's (rarely) useful to be able to get out of an inner nested loop to an outer iteration level. I don't think I've ever used it across many thousands of lines of code. In the example code posted in the original question, the label has no apparent purpose.

Comment: is it always used with `break` and `continue`. other jump possibilty ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland it can also be used with `continue`. There is no `goto` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

It is called [Labels *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) in javascript

```
myPrettyLabel:
{
   alert('testMe');
}
```

> **Provides a statement with an identifier that you can refer to using a break or continue statement.**
>
> *For example, you can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the break or continue statements to indicate whether a program should interrupt the loop or continue its execution.*

Same as `goto` in general programs

---

### Please note

**Avoid using labels** as Labels are not very commonly used in JavaScript since they make programs harder to read and understand. As much as possible, avoid using labels and, depending on the cases, prefer calling functions or throwing an error.

---

Reference: [SO - What does the colon (:) in JavaScript represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7147298/468718)

Comment: and how would you jump to this myPrettyLabel label from somewhere in the code?

Comment: there are various examples provided on mozilla developer network [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) which i have already mentioned in my answer.. btw don't get me wrong but you should reconsider all answer even though you have accepted answer... as the one accepted I dnt see much effort by or helpful from developers perspective. Rest have a nice time..

Answer (score -1):

The colon is used to add a label. As explained by the [MDN documentation for label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

> Provides a statement with an identifier that you can refer to using a break or continue statement.
>
> For example, you can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the break or continue statements to indicate whether a program should interrupt the loop or continue its execution.

MDN includes a code example as well:

```
var i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   //The second for statement is labeled "loop2"
      if (i == 1 && j == 1) {
         continue loop1;
      } else {
         console.log("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
      }
   }
}

// Output is:
//   "i = 0, j = 0"
//   "i = 0, j = 1"
//   "i = 0, j = 2"
//   "i = 1, j = 0"
//   "i = 2, j = 0"
//   "i = 2, j = 1"
//   "i = 2, j = 2"
// Notice how it skips both "i = 1, j = 1" and "i = 1, j = 2"
```

Also, as the article states, this kind of logic generally makes your code harder to understand, so you are better off restructuring the code to use other types of flow control (functions, etc) to avoid having to use labels.

---

Note that this syntax might be confusing since it is also similar to the object syntax, for example:

```
{ js: {1}, ... }
```