# What the heck operator ":" is for?

Tags: javascript

If you put on the console smth like `a: "Hi"` it does not show any error but it prints the value. But when you put `a` , it says that the variable does not exist. So, why is that? I know colons are used for defining properties inside a json object, but why is that example does not throw an error from the begging.

EDIT : I am looking for the use of colons out of a json object. Not in a `switch` statement either.

Comment: A [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ':' (colon) do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-colon-do-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the colon (:) in JavaScript represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147273/what-does-the-colon-in-javascript-represent)

Comment: no, its not. Those questions didn't respond it. As I stated on the original question,  I was not looking for the use of the colon inside a json object

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). They can be used with `continue` and `break` when doing nested loops or nested switches, but you'll almost never run into them. Due to their rarity they may cause confusion, and so i'd generally recommend against using them unless you have a compelling reason to do so.

```js
outer:
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   inner:
   for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      console.log(i, j)
      if (j == 2) {
         break outer;
      }
   }
}
```